# Submit app windows phone fail

Tags: windows-phone-7

I submit app on windows phone store. I receive messages:Certification failed. In error file Microsoft send for me, they don't show detail error for me. Nomally, If my app has error, I will receive message "Result: Failed", number of error in error file. I dont' know error in my app can't repair it. What is solution for that, please tell me.

Detail my error file:

Application Test Details:
Capabilities Tested: Networking
Language(s): Vietnamese
Result: None
Failure Summary:None
Exception(s) Applied:None

Thanks!!!

Comment: You're not going to be able to get help about your specific error that even you aren't sure of. You should try contacting the Windows Phone Dev Center support, check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj159132

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling your pain, I've been there before. This site should describe all errors that will be caught during app submission:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206735(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I submit about 10 apps. App is a ebook. Source code is the same and they have different content. But 4 apps have successfully passed and 6 apps fail. I don't know why.:(

Comment: Store spam perhaps :)